# Displaying the number of lines you have selected in Visual Mode?

Tags: visual-mode

Is there a command to display a count of the number of lines you have selected in Visual Mode in VIM?

Comment: Isn't this information displayed bottom-left side of the window when you are in visual-mode ?

Comment: If you do `:set showcmd` Vim will also display the number of lines visually selected.

Comment: You can also add `:set showcmd` to your .vimrc. Should be automatically on if `nocompatible` is set. http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27showcmd%27

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>g</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> will spit out something like this:

```
Selected 10 of 4123 Lines; 67 of 11111 Words; 400 of 40000 Bytes
```